# Are revenge (non serial) down votes allowed?

Tags: support, down-votes

Serial down votes can be automatically detected, so all serial down votes are reverted.

But say that user A gives a down vote to user B, and after 30 seconds user B takes the last recent answer of user A, and down votes it, is that allowed by rules? And can it be detected?

Comment: Yup, it's allowed. It stinks, but happens occasionally. Just ignore it, all the downvoter did what admit they are childish and petty

Comment: If they *admit* that they're voting for revenge in a comment, and specifically state that they downvoted your post *only* because they think you downvoted them, then consider flagging.  If no such comment exists, there is no way to prove their motive, and thus nothing can be done.

Comment: "Ramy, just to let u know: It want me, who down voted you. it would be nice if you finally would stop voting down random post written by me." Is that considered an admission? I down voted some answer of this user because they were bad, but he seems to do that for revenge.Shall I report that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it *allowed*? Depends on what you mean by "allowed".

Will it be detected? No, so it's allowed.

Is it douchey and counter to what a vote should be used for? Yes, so it isn't.

You decide.

Answer (score 8):

How can you prove that it is for "revenge"? No computer can detect that. And from your perspective, how do you know it is user B and not user C or G or P...?

Comment: Maybe the fact that it has come after 30 seconds, even though it's not 100% sure. I'll ignore it thanks.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri This website receives a *lot* of traffic in 30 seconds.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Here's a very common use case: 1) Someone downvotes my answer and leaves a comment explaining why 2) I read their comment, know it to be an incorrect criticism, and explain why the answer is right in comments. 3) I read their answer, since they brought me back to the question and I'm curious. 4) I see that their answer is wrong, for the reason(s) I've already explained in the comment to my post.  5) I downvote their answer, since it's wrong.  -- There's no way to tell the difference between this and a revenge downvote.

Comment: If you suspect someone specific, you can detect it by going to their profile and looking for the -1 they just sustained. It *could* be coincidence, but...

Comment: @ire_and_curses It doesn't show other users the -1 from downvoting answers.